# Launching exe using Process hangs on user input in c#

Tags: c#

I am launching an exe using below code.I am able to run exe successfully but it haults for user input which asks user to enter a character'y' or 'n'(i.e. yes/No).**What I want is that while running exe (silent installation i.e. no cmd window is available or no user interaction) i should be able to pass 'y' character as user input.**

**Below is my code**

```
public bool launchExe(exeFilepath)
{
 bool status = true;
            try
            {
                using (var myProcess = new Process())
                {
                    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = exeFilepath;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Launcher.exe";
                    myProcess.Start();
                    myProcess.WaitForExit();
                    if (myProcess.ExitCode == 0)
                        status = true;
                    else
                        status = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Information(ex.Message);
                status = false;
            }
            return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput` to write to your launched `Process`:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = exeFilepath;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

myProcess.Start();
Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait 1 second
StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("y");
```

Comment: I tried with the standardInput.But exception is thrown at line myProcess.Start() saying that  **system can not find the file specified**.I have verified for exe file location using File.Exists(....) it returns true but not working for below code.....

Comment: myProcess.Start();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    StreamWriter sw = myProcess.StandardInput;
                    sw.WriteLine("y");
                    myProcess.WaitForExit();

Comment: exeFileLocation=@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Avt\~xyz\6.10.2536.04\Uninstall\" this is my startInfo.WorkingDirectory and Launcher.exe is startInfo.FileName